# Decrypt string by other string in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

I have two strings as bellow:

```
String A = 29CEDC4A435DD625 (key)
String B = 5272B624753D79AF (encodedText)
```

I try to do decrypt string B by String A to get out the result: 8BC141DCC122B74F but don't successful with the decrypt function as follow:

```
public static string Decrypt (string encodedText, string key)
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desCrytoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] byteHash;
    byte[] byteBuff;

    byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    desCrytoProvider.Key = byteHash;
    desCrytoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);

    string plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(desCrytoProvider.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
    return plaintext;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't successful"? Do you get a different result than you expect (and if so, what result do you get)? Do you get an exception (and if so, what's the message and where does it occur)? How did you come up with your expected result (i.e., how do you know the result is wrong)?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` one place and `Convert.FromBase64String` another place? These look like hexadecimal strings, which means neither of those methods are likely to be the right thing to use.

Comment: Thank you very much @JoeWhite. Yes. I get an exception and expected result:  8BC141DCC122B74F

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a trouble with converting from byte array to String and vice versa. Try to use Convert.ToBase64String(...), Convert.FromBase64String(...). It works:

```
    static TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desCrytoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    static MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String key = "29CEDC4A435DD625";//(key)

        String encodedText = Encrypt("just4fun", key);
        Console.WriteLine(Decrypt(encodedText, key));
    }

    public static String Encrypt(String text, String key)
    {
        byte[] byteHash;
        byte[] byteBuff;

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(bytes);
        desCrytoProvider.Key = byteHash;
        desCrytoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        byteBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(desCrytoProvider.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
    }

    public static String Decrypt(String encodedText, String key)
    {
        byte[] byteHash;
        byte[] byteBuff;

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(bytes);
        desCrytoProvider.Key = byteHash;
        desCrytoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(desCrytoProvider.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andr3y, Thank you very much for your suggest.